# How to implement mutation function of genetic algorithm in R?

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm, mutation

I'm implementing GA algorithm. The chromosomes have a combination of **-1,0,1** values. In the mutation part, I want to change -1 to 1 with **prob(-1 to 1)** and change 1 to -1 with **prob(1 to -1)**.
I don't know if there is any function in R which would make it easy for me. Would any one tell me if there is a function which helps me replace the values according to their probability?

Comment: Wouldn't probability depend on your model?

Comment: No, the probabilities are pre-defined. @RomanLuštrik

Comment: How do you store values? Please provide a small example and desired output.

Comment: I work on a vector (or list). If input is : `1,-1,1,0,-1` and the probability of converting 1 to -1 is 0.1 , then the output might be : `-1,-1,1,0,-1`. Because of the probability, the output is not determined.

Answer (score 1):

You could throw a dice and if 1 comes up, you change the original value to another value. You could add if statements for all of your transitions. If you mean to mutate the whole string in one step, this can be better optimized.

```
from <- c(1,-1,1,0,-1)

probToMutate <- function(x) {
    if (x == 1) {
        dice <- rbinom(1, size = 1, prob = 0.1)
        if (dice == 1) {
            x <- -1
        } else {
            x <- 1
        }
    } else {
        x
    }
}

sapply(from, FUN = probToMutate)
```